# Is there any way to use MongoDB with TestCafe?

Tags: mongodb, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How does one get value from MongoDB into a live running TestCafe test so it will type that value out during the test?  I have a MongoDB collection full of data that I want TestCafe to use during live tests.  I expected to use .toArray() within the TestCafe file but I can't even get a MongoDB connection it seems.  Nowhere online have I found the solution to this yet.

I've already attempted to follow the steps below:

1. Added MongoClient to my test.js (TestCafe file) code.
2. Within this code, I attempted to just display "connected to database".
3. I never see "connected to database" within the terminal or anywhere else.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
import fs from 'fs';
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
const assert = require('assert');


// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'my_database_name';

// keyword begins as an empty string and is supposed to be populated from DB
var keyword = [];

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('my_collection_name');
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({'a': 3}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs);
    callback(docs);
    keyword.unshift(docs);    
  });
};


  client.close();
});

keyword = keyword[0]

fixture `example`
    .page `https://www.google.com/`;

test('mongodb keyword to google search', async t => {
    await t
     .wait(1000)
     .maximizeWindow()
     .wait(1000)
     .typeText(Selector('input[name="q"]'), keyword) //docs['keyword']
     .wait(1000)
     .presKey('enter') 
        .wait(5000);

});
```

So, I tried to show a simple google search that attempts to insert a keyword from my MongoDB collection into the Google search box and press the search button.  This should be easy enough:

1. Run test
2. Supposed to connect to MongoDB, get a single keyword from the "example_collection"
3. Type that keyword into Google and press search.

Instead, I get this error:

```
(node:1900) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use|
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 74.0.3729 / Windows 10.0.0

 example
 × MongoDB keyword to google search

   1) The "text" argument is expected to be a non-empty string, but it was undefined.

      Browser: Chrome 74.0.3729 / Windows 10.0.0

         64 |test('mongodb keyword to google search', async t => {
         65 |    await t
         66 |     .wait(1000)
         67 |     .maximizeWindow()
         68 |     .wait(1000)
       > 69 |     .typeText(Selector('input[name="q"]'), keyword) //docs['keyword']
         70 |     .wait(1000)
         71 |     .presKey('enter')
         72 |        .wait(5000);
         73 |
         74 |});

         at typeText (C:\Users\Eric\Google Drive\!GIF
      PROJECT\JavaScript\NodeJS\TestCafe\stackoverflow_example.js:69:7)
         at test (C:\Users\TestCafe\PROJECT\JavaScript\NodeJS\TestCafe\stackoverflow_example.js:64:1)
         at markeredfn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe\src\api\wrap-test-function.js:17:28)
         at <anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe\src\api\wrap-test-function.js:7:5)
         at fn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe\src\test-run\index.js:240:19)
         at TestRun._executeTestFn
      (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe\src\test-run\index.js:236:38)
         at _executeTestFn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe\src\test-run\index.js:289:24)
```

Please let me know if there is a solution to this.  I just want to pass database data (from MongoDB) into TestCafe so it's used during the test (also if I wanted to load URLs from a database, also need to know it).

1/1 failed (2s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoClient.connect` is an asynchronous API with a callback function. Its completion is not guaranteed at the time you access the `keyword` value in the test. You can wrap this function in a Promise and use the `await` keyword in the test to retrieve results from the database:

```js
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'my_database_name';

function findDocs (db) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const collection = db.collection('my_collection_name');

        // Find some documents
        collection.find({'a': 3}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            console.log("Found the following records");
            console.log(docs);
            resolve(docs);
        });
    });
}

function getClient () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Use connect method to connect to the server
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

            console.log("Connected successfully to server");

            resolve(client);
        });
    });
}

async function getKeywords () {
    const client = await getClient();
    const db     = client.db(dbName);

    try {
        return await getDocs(db);
    }
    finally {
        client.close();
    }
}

fixture `example`
    .page `https://www.google.com/`;

test('mongodb keyword to google search', async t => {
    const keyword = await getKeywords();

    await t
     .wait(1000)
     .maximizeWindow()
     .wait(1000)
     .typeText(Selector('input[name="q"]'), keyword) //docs['keyword']
     .wait(1000)
     .presKey('enter') 
        .wait(5000);

});
```